# Anaconda as default application in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I've just started programming in Python, I use Visual Studio 2015 as my IDE, and I have installed Anaconda, but it's not my default Python environment. For example, when I want to draw something with Python it says "matplot required for draw()".

I changed the path in my computer to "C:\Users\Maryam\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Maryam\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Maryam\Anaconda3\Library\bin" and also in Visual Studio in menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment*, I change the path to "C:\Users\Maryam\Anaconda3\python.exe" and also I have changed windows and library paths, but still I can't work with Anaconda in Visual Studio. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In the *Python Environments* window, when you selected interpreter, below it is option *"Make this default environment for new projects"*. Press it

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Here is an [article that might answer your question](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration).

It looks like you should install the free *Python Tools For Visual Studio* extension:

> your default Python installation and installed PTVS, your Visual Studio installation is already set to use Anaconda’s Python interpreter in PTVS.

Comment: I installed Python Tools for Visual Studio, but in python interactive window when I type sys.version , Anaconda python version is not displayed